# Get contents of a local page into another page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get only some specific `<div>` elements from a page (on my PC, say `source.html` ) to another page, say `index.html`. I am using jQuery ajax for the purpose and my `index.html` has a script like:

```
$.ajax({url: "source.html", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
```

I just wrote it to check if I am actually getting anything or not but to my dismay, I get nothing on my page.

I opened the browser console and got the following errors:

```
Mismatched tag: Expected </meta> : source.html
Mismatched tag: Expected </meta> : index.html
```

I am not really able to guess what might be the reason for these errors?
Is this the right way? 
Any help?
Thanks.

Edit:
My HTML starts like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cuckoo Sandbox</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<style>
Styling here
</style>
</head>
```

My HTML is very large ( Hence I want to extract only some info), but I am redirected to this last head tag, when I click on the error.

Comment: Can you post your complete HTML? Is `source.html` a template or a regular webpage?

Comment: @RahulDesai, Please see the edits.

Comment: I didnt get the answer to my second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#div1").load("source.html #someDiv");
```

Make Sure you have `jquery.js` or `jquery.min.js` included in your HTML. I don't see it in your HTML snippet

Comment: Yes, it loads the entire page, but how do I get only some elements? The problem is that the source html doesn't have any id's assigned to the elements, I just want to work around with nth-child of body. How to do that?

Comment: can you paste the HTML from `source.html` ? So I can provide you more accurate reply.